# How to set Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled to false when my DbContext is an Interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

So I created an interface to facilitate testing my WebApi controller.

```
public interface IApplicationDbContext
{
    IDbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
    IDbSet<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Here's my controller

```
public class OrderLinesController : ApiController
{
    private IApplicationDbContext _db;
    public OrderLinesController(IApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
...
}
```

So my question is how do set _db's Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled as if it were a concrete ApplicationDbContext?

Comment: Add a property `ProxyCreationEnabled` to your interface, and in the implementing class use it to set `_db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled`. Then, simply set the property in the `OrderLinesController`.

Comment: why do you want that? if it's for testing - just mock `DbSet`s with concrete types, not proxies. set `Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled` in realization of this interface and IoC container will inject your realization with your desired `Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled`.

Comment: @ieagle Interfaces have benefits over the concrete class when it comes to mocking.

Comment: @james, that is true, but it's not the case here. interface should define a **contract**. each individual realization of this interface should define a **behaviour**. changing `ProxyCreationEnabled` is not a **contract**, it's **behaviour**. if your `IApplicationDbContext ` realization, that you are injecting into `OrderLinesController`s constructor, changes `ProxyCreationEnabled` - oka. for unit testing you don't event need to do any changes, you have full control of what to return.

Comment: @ieagle okay lets suppose ProxyCreationEnabled is a behavior, but that is the consequence of adding it as a property. If suppose i have not applied it as Maarteen suggested, then surely the SaveChanges(), Entry(), and the IDbSets still hold as contracts.